# SEM-LPA model fit using BIC

Tags: self-study, structural-equation-modeling, bic, iid, latent-class

I am studying a paper and while I have done a lot of additional reading, I would like some hints on on this issue as I am somewhat stuck.

My question is whether a Structural Equation Model of the Latent Profile sub-type would require random IID probability sampling in order to use BIC to test model fit?

Answer (score 1):

The BIC is just a negative log likelihood plus a penalty for the number of parameters. If the data are not IID, you have to account for it with the correct log likelihood. If so there's no problem.

Comment: What statistics of the sample determine the correct log-likelihood? If this is not correct, then the uncertainty estimates of model fit increase? I.e, the model has a lower probability of explaining the data?

Comment: Unfortunately, no statistics will tell you whether you have specified the correct likelihood. Ironically the wrong likelihood can be more likely in a sample than the right one. You can justify your choice of likelihood by describing the sample, the design, and the type of dependence or distributional differences that arise.